# How to check whether user already authenticated via UDP

Tags: sockets, network-programming, udp

Suppose that I have to write a UDP server which should receive authentication token for each client in the first message and then receive different data after some period of time. This UDP server should obviously check whether certain client authenticated previously or not. How should I do it? Should I store "authenticated" flag for each (IP addr, port) pair? Is it ok? If so, what will happen if several clients will have the same IP address (for example, they share it from the same internet provider)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't.  You'll need to have the token in each message.  Multiple requests can come from the same IP, such as a client connecting from behind a NAT.

Answer (score 0):

This a rare case where you might want to use multiple UDP sockets at the server and `connect()` each of them to one authenticated client, so that you can only receive further messages on each one from each authenticated client. You'll have to send the first reply via hat socket,a denture client will have to be written to adjust its destination accordingly after receiving the first reply.

Comment: So I should have a UDP socket for each connected client, right?